# Office 365 Add-Ins are severely clipped horizontally in Firefox 53

Tags: css, firefox, office365, add-in, outlook-web-addins

After upgrading to Firefox, our O365 Mail/Outlook Add-In is rendering with significant horizontal clipping and as a result, a scroll bar is presented in order to move down up and down the Add-In UI. All other browsers render the full Add-In properly - no scroll bar needed.

Other Add-Ins are likely to have something similar and I see a related item 
[flex not working in firefox 53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43548008/flex-not-working-in-firefox-53) but our issue is related to O365 add-ins - similar root issue I expect

The addin is loaded within an iframe so dev cannot change the parent window code given the different domain.

Any solutions or news on a fix would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a space missing after the '%' in *height: calc(100%- 66px);* in the stylesheet from microsoft. But i can't find a good bug form...

without space:

```
.o365-EXTP-app {
    width: 100%;
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 66px);
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 66px);
    height: calc(100%- 66px);
}
```

with space

```
.o365-EXTP-app {
    width: 100%;
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 66px);
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 66px);
    height: calc(100% - 66px);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue and we are working to resolve it soon.

Comment: This issue is also present in OWA on Exchange 2016 CU6 with Firefox 55.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same issue in Firefox 53.0. After the Firefox being updated to 53.0.2, this issue is gone.

Comment: Great news - we will give it a whirl with our Add-on